# Woocommerce problem about array items in cart

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

This is my code in cart:

```
<?php 
$totaleiva_1 = 0;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item ) {
    echo $totaleforsebene;
    $totaleiva_1 = $totaleiva_1 + $totaleforsebene;
}
echo $totaleiva_1;
?>
```

The result is: the `$totaleforsebene` value of the last product in cart is added n times for product I have (for example I have two products, the last value `$totaleforsebene` is added two times).

Instead, I would want to have the `$totaleforsebene` for different products and then They are been added.

Thanks for help

Comment: From where do you get the `$totaleforsebene` value for each product/item? are it set on each `$item` in the cart or you have pre-define array with item ID as keys and `$totaleforsebene` as values?

Comment: This value is a sum

Comment: A sum for what? it seems like `$totaleiva_1` is the sum you creating. If you want to add different `$totaleforsebene` per item we need to know from where do you get it

Comment: <?php 
  global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
           echo "<b>".$product->get_title().'</b>  <br> Quantità: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
            $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
   $carrello = $values['quantity'] * $price;
   global $dsc_table; 
   $code = $coupon->get_code();
   $amounttax = WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount($code, WC()->cart->display_cart_ex_tax);

Comment: $amount = WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount($code);
  $total = $woocommerce->cart->total;
  $totale2 = $amounttax + $total;
  $division = ($amounttax / $totale2)*100;
 $division = number_format($division, 2, '.', '')." %";
$sconto = ($carrello * $division) / 100;
$scontato = $carrello - $sconto;
$scontato = number_format($scontato, 2, '.', '')." €";
echo "  Totale scontato: ".$scontato."<br>";

Comment: global $woocommerce;
 $with_tax = $price;
 $without_tax = $product->get_price_excluding_tax();
 $tax_amount = $with_tax - $without_tax;
 $percent = ($tax_amount / $without_tax) * 100;
 echo 'IVA al ' . $percent . '%';
 echo "<br>";
if ($percent == "10") 
$tax_rate= 10; 
else $tax_rate= 4;                      
$with_tax = $scontato; 
$totaleforsebene = ($scontato * $percent)/100;
$totaleforsebene = number_format($totaleforsebene, 2, '.', '')." €";
echo "  Iva sul totale: ".$totaleforsebene."<br>";
echo "<br>";
        } 
         ?>

Comment: Update your question with the code, please. It is unreadable in comments and might get deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create array with ID for each product and then add the correct value:

When you calculate the `$totaleforsebene` do this:

```
foreach($items as $item => $values) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());
    ...
    $totaleforsebene = ($scontato * $percent)/100; 
    $totalForSebeneArray[$values['data']->get_id()] = $totaleforsebene; // add the value by the item ID
    $totaleforsebene = number_format($totaleforsebene, 2, '.', '')." €"; 
}
```

Now, when you loop on the item and sum you can do:

```
$totaleiva_1 = 0;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item ) {
    $totaleiva_1 += $totalForSebeneArray[$item ['data']->get_id()];
}
echo $totaleiva_1;
```

You also need to format your question better as now it is very hard to understand your issue and I am not even sure if my explanation answer your problem...

Comment: foreach($items as $item => $values) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());
    $totaleforsebene = number_format($totaleforsebene, 2, '.', '')." €"; 
    $totalForSebeneArray[$values['data']->get_id()] = $totaleforsebene; // add the value by the item ID
}

Comment: foreach($items as $item => $values) {$product = wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); $totaleforsebene = number_format($totaleforsebene, 2, '.', '')." €"; 
    $totalForSebeneArray[$values['data']->get_id()] = $totaleforsebene; 
} $totaleiva_1 = 0;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item ) {
    $totaleiva_1 += $totalForSebeneArray[$item ['data']->get_id()];
} echo $totaleiva_1; in this way?

Comment: What??? I'm really do not understand. Please avoid post code in comments. Did you understood my post?

Comment: Sorry for comments. I have made two trials: 1) I insert this code foreach($items as $item => $values) before $with_tax = $scontato but in a product (the first) I have zero value in the second product I have 2 times 10.54 (two times of value of the first product) 2) insert the code at the end of this code And I have 1.9 (two times of value the second product) Thanks for patience

Comment: ok thank you so much. I have seen the code and it works!! thank you!

Comment: I have another question. How can I put this data $totaleiva_1 and  $totaleiva_1 += $totalForSebene in order email? Thank you so much

Comment: If you want to email the sum result its a total different question - I suggest you separate it to new post